# Cannot infer type for generic type parameter in struct

Tags: generics, rust

I'm currently trying to implement base64 encoding/decoding in rust as part of a larger project and needed a data structure for mapping the base64 character set to ASCII and vice versa. I found a barebones implementation of a bidirectional `HashMap` in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613305/how-can-i-model-a-bidirectional-map-without-annoying-the-borrow-checker), but since I need the base64 map to be a global variable in order for both encode/decode functions to access it, I can't just add the character mappings one by one. So I added another function to the `BidiMap` implementation that does it in one batch (other function implementations are the same as in the link above):

```
impl<A, B> BidiMap<A, B>
where
  A: Eq + Hash,
  B: Eq + Hash,
{

// ...

  pub fn from_array_with_u8_indices(values: &[B]) -> BidiMap<u8, B>
    where B: Copy,
  {
    if values.len() > u8::MAX as usize + 1 {
      panic!("This function should only be called with an array whose indices fit into an u8.");
    }
    let mut map: BidiMap<u8, B> = BidiMap::new();

    for i in 0..values.len() {
      map.insert(i as u8, values[i]);
    }

    map
  }

// ...

}
```

I then call this function in another file, base64.rs:

```
use crate::datastructures::bidi_map::BidiMap;

const base64_values: [u8; 65] = [
  0x41, 0x42, 0x43, ... , 0x3D,
];
const base64_map: BidiMap<u8, u8> = BidiMap::from_array_with_u8_indices(&base64_values);
```

But when I try to compile this code, I get the error

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/encodings/base64.rs:10:37
   |
10 | const base64_map: BidiMap<u8, u8> = BidiMap::from_array_with_u8_indices(&base64_values);
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `A`
```

Even though I specified the types for `A` and `B` with `BidiMap<u8, u8>`. I am pretty new to programming in rust and with generics in general, so it could be that I'm missing something really obvious, but I can't figure out what the solution to this problem is. I've already tried to change the function signature and implementation to return `Self` instead of `BidiMap<u8, B>`, but then it complained about not being able to cast the array indices to a generic type `A` when calling `map.insert()`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. In the future, try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then edit your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) tips you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you write `impl<A, B> BidiMap<A, B>` but then return a `BidiMap<u8, B>`, hardcoding what you probably wanted to be `A`, thereby giving the compiler no clue what the type parameter `A` should be. If you change the return type of `from_array_with_u8_indices` to `BidiMap<A, B>` or change the implementation to `impl<B> BidiMap<u8, B>` it should compile just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [minimal example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6a963462bd5dda85262def0216c5c437) to reproduce your issue.

As you noted, the **return** type for `from_array_with_u8_indices` is indeed correctly inferred.

However, the **concrete** type for `BidiMap::from_array_with_u8_indices` cannot be inferred because the method is implemented for `BidiMap<A, B>`. The return type is not related to this type.

Two possible fixes:

#### Specify the concrete type explicitly using the turbofish syntax:

```
let map = BidiMap::<u8, u8>::from_array_with_u8_indices(&base64_values);
```

#### Create a specific implementation for the type you know you are returning:

```
impl<B> BidiMap<u8, B>
where
    B: Eq + Hash,
{
    pub fn from_array_with_u8_indices(values: &[B]) -> Self
    where
        B: Copy,
    {
        let mut map: BidiMap<u8, B> = BidiMap::new();
        //...
        map
    }
}
```

in which case you don't need to specify the type at all:

```
let base64_map = BidiMap::from_array_with_u8_indices(&base64_values);
```

[Example of working code in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a7ed8bc20e48750d82eaeba14dcc7176)